# Multiple background images, different elements overlap

Tags: css, background-image

For a better UX, I'm showing the empty profile image as a background until the real profile image is loaded, & I'm using [Multiple Backgrounds feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) to achieve this behavior, like in the following screenshot:

[image]

The **html** look something like:

```
<ul>
    <li><span id='span-id' class="img-circle profile-image"><span></li>
    <li ...
</ul>
```

The **CSS** look something like:

```
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 150px;
}
.profile-image {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The **js** look something like:

```
var url = 'profile-image-url-here';// depends on user's profile of course
var anonymousUrl = 'anonymous-profile-image-here';
var backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ") , url(" + anonymousUrl + ")";
$('#span-id').css('background-image', backgroundImage);
```

## The Issue is:

While the previous code works fine in almost all scenarios/browsers, some android devices (their Chrome browser & even webviews) repeat the images in a very weird way like the following screenshot:

[image]

So, Why is this happening?!! .. & how to prevent it?

(I'm sure that the issue is not in the data, because each image has a link to the user's profile & links are already pointing to different profiles)

Comment: Why not using a pseudo + background instead of javascript?

Comment: Because the content itself is dynamic, those profile images are not fixed, they are chosen randomly

Comment: Check the width of your <span id='span-id' class="img-circle profile-image"> for those instances when multiple pictures appear.

Based on the code posted here looks like the width is auto (display: block) and it might get bigger depending on the viewport / responsive aspect which might allow multiple backgrounds to be shown.